# Load data using list?

Tags: c#

I'm having trouble loading my data.

```
private class StoredData
{
    public int NombreJoueurs;
    public List<pList> Joueurs;
    public class pList
    {
        public string Equipe;
    }
}
private StoredData storedData;
void LoadData()
{
    storedData = Interface.Oxide.DataFileSystem.ReadObject<StoredData>("cEvent");
    }

    private void Loaded()
    {
        LoadData();
    }
```

If I do this, I don't have to worry about it, it's worth 50

```
Console.WriteLine(storedData.NombreJoueurs);
```

But if I do this, I get no feedback from the foreach or out of the loop I get this error message

```
storedData.Joueurs = new List<StoredData.pList>();

foreach (var j in storedData.Joueurs)
{
       Console.WriteLine(j.Equipe);
}
```

> Type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Oxide.Plugins.cEvent.StoredData.pList>'
>    does not contain a definition for 'Equipe' and no extension method
>   'Equipe' of type
>    'System.Collections.Generic.List<Oxide.Plugins.cEvent.StoredData.pList>'
>    could be found.

My data

```
{
      "76561198969362505": {
            "Equipe": "A"
      },
      "76561198454481509": {
            "Equipe": "b"
      },
      "NombreJoueurs": 50,
}
```

Thank you

Comment: is there a reason why you have that class, `pList` declared within your other class ?

Comment: you should change your JSON structure ...

Comment: Your JSON and your model do not match

Comment: I just tested your code here.. works fine. [dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HKp2IS). You must have declared your class, `StoredData` differently than what you have posted here. Check if you changed Equipe to a List perhaps in your code.

Comment: Not sure what deserialize library you are using, but converting Joueours to dictionary works fine with Newtonsoft. Fiddler is https://dotnetfiddle.net/GOD7QL. I also pasted the same in my answer below.

Comment: I don't have access to the Newtonsoft library with my plugins.

Comment: @crazyz I just took Newtonsoft as an example to show the json output by converting Joueurs to Dictionary since I do not know the functionality of `Interface.Oxide.DataFileSystem.ReadObject`. As you see in the fiddler, output of json produced in fiddler is same (structure) as your JSON DATA that you posted here.

Comment: @Jawad: your fiddler seems to be doing something different. You are re-assigning Joueurs  with some sample data after deserializing and that is what you are printing to console.

Comment: My data is generated by another code. Now I'm trying to recover it. That's why my builder's probably different than json's like you said.

Comment: @crazyz your json does not correctly translate to your class. You are using List<pList> but there is nothing in json that says there is a list. You have multiple properties with Equipe variable in it... You will need to find a way to acecss each of these random numbered properties ..not via List<pList> though

Comment: @Jawad That's what exactly I mentioned in my answer. Not sure why its downvoted.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thank you. But how am I supposed to get that list if she doesn't have a name?

Comment: @crazyz, please try changing datatype of Joueurs to Dictionary as shown in my answer below and post your observations. Dictionary matches with your json structure that you posted here.

Comment: I dont konw what Interface does and how it translates/reads your "cEvent". Once you have the text of the said cEvent, use JObject.Parse and iterate through its `Properties`

Comment: I try a lot of. I couldn't do it. does not contain a definition for `Equipe' and no extension method `Equipe'

Comment: @crazyz not sure whom you are responding to - me or Jawad. But if its to me, then could you please update your post with what you have tried and what error you are getting . Thank you in advance.

Comment: I tried both solutions by modifying my code each time an error occurred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to change your class structure a bit and use a custom JSON converter.  You will have to use a dictionary of type `public IDictionary<string, pList> Joueurs;`.  Full fiddler is [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g8TtnW)

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(StoredDataConverter))]
public class StoredData
{
    public int NombreJoueurs;
    public IDictionary<string, pList> Joueurs;
}
public class pList
{
    public string Equipe;

}

public class StoredDataConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
    public override bool CanRead => base.CanRead;

    public override bool CanWrite => base.CanWrite;

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(StoredData).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var storedData = new StoredData();
        JObject obj = JObject.Load(reader);
        IDictionary<string, pList> dict = (IDictionary<string, pList>)existingValue ?? new Dictionary<string, pList>();
        foreach (var prop in obj.Properties())
        {
            if (prop.Name != "NombreJoueurs")
            {
                var jtoken = JToken.Parse(prop.Value.ToString());

                dict.Add(prop.Name, jtoken.ToObject<pList>());
            }
            else
                storedData.NombreJoueurs = (int)prop.Value;

        }
        storedData.Joueurs = dict;
        return storedData;
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
class Program
{
    private static StoredData storedData;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        storedData = LoadData();

        Console.WriteLine(storedData.NombreJoueurs);
        foreach (var item in storedData.Joueurs)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}:{((pList)item.Value).Equipe}");
        }
    }

    private static StoredData LoadData()
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StoredData>("{ \"76561198969362505\": {\"Equipe\": \"A\"},\"76561198454481509\": {\"Equipe\": \"b\"},\"NombreJoueurs\": 50}");

    }
}
```

Comment: I know its accepted as answer, but just wanted to share my thought that I don't think we need StoredDataConverter as Newtonsoft will deserialize out of the box to StoredData.

Comment: @sam Thanks for the input.  I ran the code with the sample you provided and NewtonSoft does not appear to bind the `Joueurs` dictionary.  Is there a JSON attribute we are missing on the property?

Comment: @salli please refer the fiddler(https://dotnetfiddle.net/GOD7QL) attached to my answer.

Comment: @Sam. I think you provided a great solution to serialize the object properly.  However, I think the original question was the deserialize JSON to object when the JsonProperty key is dynamic.

Comment: @salli When you are able to serialize out of the box, deserialize also happens out of the box. Feel free to extend my sample to deserialize jsonStr via JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StoredData>(jsonStr). It will be properly deserialized.

Comment: @Sam.  Notice the JSON is a bit different format from what @crazyz needed to consume.  I think a better answer to this would be a class structure that can be serialized out of the box if possible.  Neither of our solutions is that structure.
`{ 
   "NombreJoueurs":0,
   "Joueurs":{ 
      "76561198969362505":{ 
         "Equipe":"A"
      },
      "76561198969362515":{ 
         "Equipe":"b"
      }
   }
}`

Answer (score 0):

@sam i only used that

```
private static StoredData storedData;
private static StoredData LoadData()
{
    return Interface.Oxide.DataFileSystem.ReadObject<StoredData>("cEvent");
}

public class StoredData
{
    public int NombreJoueurs;
    public IDictionary<string, pList> Joueurs;
}

public class pList
{
    public string Equipe;
}

private void Loaded()
{
    storedData = LoadData();
}
private void CopieStats()
{
    Console.WriteLine(storedData.NombreJoueurs);
    foreach (var item in storedData.Joueurs)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{item.Key}:{((pList)item.Value).Equipe}");
    }
}
```